# Caffe convert_imageset with one class/ label

Tags: neural-network, lmdb, caffe

I want to create an lmdb dataset from images which part of them contain the feature I want caffe to learn, and part of them don't.
My question is - in the text input file transferred to convert_imageset - how should I label those images that don't contain the feature?
I know the format is

```
PATH_TO_IMAGE LABEL
PATH_TO_IMAGE LABEL
PATH_TO_IMAGE LABEL
```

But which label should I assign to images **without** the feature?
For example, img1.jpg contain the feature, img2.jpg and img3.jpg don't.
So should the text file look like -

```
img1.jpg 0
img2.jpg 1?
img3.jpg 1?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got an answer from [Caffe-users Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/caffe-users) - yes, creating a dummy feature is the right way for this.
So it is:

```
img1.jpg 0
img2.jpg 1
img3.jpg 1
```

Comment: can you post a link to the relevant thread in caffe-users google group?